# Jmeter Regular expression extractor and parsing into request

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, I can able to extract the value using regular expression extractor, but while parsing the value I need some changes in the value as below.

Example,
Suppose If I extract this value in regular expression extractor (single Value in multiple lines),
PHNhbW+xwO
U0FNTDoyL
cmFjbGUu+

Here
I Need to replace + by %2B, need to add %OD%OA at the end of each line and multiple lines to a single line as below.

PHNhbW%2BxwO%OD%OAU0FNTDoyL%OD%OAcmFjbGUu%2B%OD%OA

I need to parse this as a single parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function which allows calling arbitrary JavaScript code and inside JMeter __javaScript() funciton you can call EcmaScript [EncodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function

It will automatically convert all newline characters `\r\n` to `%OD%OA` and `+` to `%2B` and in fact any character except alphanumeric and these ones:

```
_ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JavaScript]

See [Using JMeter Functions](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) guide for comprehensive information on how to deal with the functions in JMeter

Comment: thank you Dmitri.

I checked encode in jmeter http request and it worked.